# A computer has 64KB of memory. How many memory locations does it have?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-address

A computer has 64KB of memory. Its addressability is 8 bytes. How many memory locations does it have? How many bits are needed to address each location in memory?

I know that 1 kb = 1024 bytes, so 64kb = 65536 bytes = 2^16 bytes

2^16 bytes / 8 bytes * 2^3 bits = 2^16 bits

Is this the number of memory locations it has?

And what does bits needed to address each location mean?

Comment: What is your definition of "memory location"?

Comment: To my understanding it is the place or space in memory where data is stored.

Comment: That definition is not precise enough to answer the question, unfortunately.

Comment: 65536 in decimal = 10 000 in hex. It is the memory address range until 0x10000. Is that what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even later answer...

64KB represents 65,536 bytes (8-bit) of memory, so there are 524,288 total bits (65,536 x 8).

In terms of addressable 8-bit memory, there are 65,536 memory locations spanning from address 0x0000 to 0xFFFF where 0x**** represents hexadecimal equivalent of decimal addresses 0 to 65,535 (a total of 65,536 locations).

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

This is late but maybe it will be of some use to others.

64 Kb means = 2 ^16 bytes.
Addressability concerns the different number of bytes we can point to. So 8 bytes = 2 ^3.

If we can address each 8 bytes out of 64Kb, that means=
2^16 / 2^3= 2^13 is your answer.